# Serving images via http createServer

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am attempting to create a basic webserver with Node.JS, but running into an issue with properly serving images.

```
var server = http.createServer(function (request, response){
    if(request.url === '/') {
        fs.readFile('public/index.html', 'utf8', function(errors, contents){
            response.write(contents); 
            response.end();
        });
    } else {
        fs.readFile("public" + request.url, 'utf8', function(errors, contents){
            if (!errors) {
                response.end(contents);
            } else {
                console.log('Failed to read file: /public' + request.url);
                response.writeHead(404);
                response.end();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Everything works fine, apart from if you go to view the image it attempts to download it (which I believe is corrupted - cant open it), which is not what I want, I wish for the images to be served properly in the browser (not via a  tag)

Bonus points: I need to be able to correctly give the proper headers (Do I need just a switch statement and set them via that?), as chrome is giving off warnings

```
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/plain: "http://localhost/css.css".
```

Comment: Both issues are gonna' be caused by a missing content type. Can't recall how that's set off the top of my head, though!

Comment: I think that `fs.readFile("public" + request.url`is unsafe by example with : `http://example.com/..\..\..\windows\myprivatefile`

Comment: Do you want to use expressjs ? http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use expressjs : http://expressjs.com/

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.sendFile('public/index.html'))
app.use(express.static('public'))

app.listen(8080, () => console.log('Example app listening on port 8080!'))
```

---

NB :

Your code is unsafe : `"public" + request.url`. Your users can get all files of your server : `fs.readFileSync("public/../../../README.txt");`

You will get error on parent folder.

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\README.txt'.

Comment: This worked, though I didn't need to use the app.get() line, as Express automatically serves the index, thank you! :)